# How do you make a call to a Twilio JavaScript softphone client?

Tags: java, twilio

I'm attempting to use the Java API helper with Twilio to make a call to the Twilio softphone running in Google Chrome. Here is my code:

```
... initialize API keys...
Client clientName = new Client( "jesse" );
PhoneNumber calerId = new PhoneNumber( "+17702349293" );
URI callAction = new URI( "https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH0c72cc88d481480a93e5947edb770449" );
Call call = Call.creator( clientName, calerId, callAction ).create();
```

I get this error message:

Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: The phone number you are attempting to call, 53773, is not valid.

It seems like Twilio is attempting to dial digits based on the letters in the client name - so "jesse" is being converted to "53773". How can I make Twilio understand that "jesse" is the name of a connected client?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: Need to change this line:

```
Client clientName = new Client( "jesse" );
```

to this:

```
Client clientName = new Client( "client:jesse" );
```

As far as I can tell, this is not documented - I figured it out from looking at the "From:" name on incoming calls.